# How can I save an axes content with it's original size in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, save, size

I'm trying to save an axes content with this code:

```
F = getframe(handles.axes3);
image=frame2im(F);
imwrite(image, fullfile(add,name));
end
```

When I save it, the saved image is of a different size that the original image.

How do I best save the image in the same size as the original image?

Comment: Show what you expect and what you've got from MATLAB

Comment: I want to load an image in an axes, convert it to gray and save it. but when I do it with above code, the image size changes to the size of the axes, but I want the image be the same size as it was!

Answer (score 0):

Based of you reply to @Leonardo's comment, if just want to convert a color image to grayscale you probably don't want to be ploting it and then saving the plot (I assume right now you're loading the image, plotting it and calling `colormap gray` or similar before running the posted code).

To convert your image to grayscale and save it something like the following would perhaps be better.

```
RGBimage = imread('Colourimage.png');
grayimage=rgb2gray(RGBimage)
imwrite(grayimage,'newGrayimage.png')
```

Comment: No, I want to load an image, do something like add noise, convert to gray or binary, changing some pixels value, etc. and finaly save the result image! I'm looking a way I can set the scale of saving image.